# RegEx for validating emails with single letter domains

Tags: regex, email

I have a regular expression which is good with all my rules except that it fails to validate email addresses with less than 3 characters in its domain:

```
^(?=(.{1,64}@.{1,255}))([-+%_a-zA-Z0-9]{1,64}(\.[-+%_a-zA-Z0-9][^.]{0,}){0,})@[^-\.@#!$&^*~`={}|'"?]([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,63}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,}){0,}[^.](?!.web)(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}){1,4})$
```

Eg It considers sample@q.com and sample@me.com as invalid emails

Regex can be found here
https://regex101.com/r/XcXIaL/1

Could anyone suggest a modification to this existing regular expression

It should accept

```
sample@q.com
sample@me.com
sample@mes.com
```

Comment: Please show your regexp in the question itself. The link should only be an additional resource.

Comment: Your regex has 3 subgroups, each has to match at least one symbol, none optional. That means you need at least 3 symbols to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we simply reduce the `{1,63}` boundary to `{0,63}`, and remove this unnecessary letter:

```
[^-\.@#!$&^*~`={}|'"?]
```

The key part of our code associated with that is:

```
[^-\.@#!$&^*~`={}|'"?]([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,63}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,}){0,}[^.](?!.web)
```

changed to:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,63}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,}){0,}[^.](?!.web)
```

and final code is:

```
^(?=(.{1,64}@.{1,255}))([-+%_a-zA-Z0-9]{1,64}(\.[-+%_a-zA-Z0-9][^.]{0,}){0,})@([a-zA-Z0-9_]{0,63}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,}){0,}[^.](?!.web)(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}){1,4})$
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/N2nagM/1)

Our modified expression is:

[image]

Comment: This does allow sample@mk.com but it still rejects sample@m.com. I want my rejegex to accept sample@m.com as well.

Comment: So, @user2990342 - now that you have the solution, do you understand what was wrong with your original RE? Emma - did you actually answer a question or did you answer a request to provide the code?